# File Finder in C

Tags: c, windows, c++11

First of all Sorry for my bad English. I am not native English.
I am going to write a program that list all available logical disk drives. Then ask the user to select a drive. then takes a file extension and searches that file type in given drive (including directories and sub-directories). Program should be able to run on windows xp and onward. It should be single stand alone application. I am not expert in C. I have some hands on C#. i have following questions in this regard.
1. Is there any IDE/Tool in which i can write C# like code that directly compiles to single stand alone application for windows?
2. Can you recommend some libs that i can use state forward for this purpose like using in C#? (I have seen dirent and studying it.)

I coppied some code that i am testing as a startup.

---

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dirent.h>
//------------------- Get list of all fixed drives in char array. only drive letter is get. not path.
//                      add ":\" to build path.
char AllDrives[26];
DWORD GetAllDrives()
{
    int AvlDrives=0;
    DWORD WorkState=-1;
//TCHAR DrivePath[] = _T("A:\\");  //Orignal Type
//start getting for drive a:\ to onward.
char DrivePath[] = {"A:\\"};

    //http://www.tenouk.com/cpluscodesnippet/getdrivetype.html
   ULONG uDriveMask = _getdrives();

   if (uDriveMask == 0)
   {
       WorkState=GetLastError();

        printf("\r\nFailed to Get drives. Error Details : %lu", WorkState);
        return WorkState;
   }
   else
   {

       WorkState=0xFF;
      printf("The following logical drives are being used:\n");

      while (uDriveMask) {
         if (uDriveMask & 1)
            {

                UINT drvType=0;
                drvType = GetDriveType(DrivePath);
                if(drvType==3)
                {
                    AllDrives[AvlDrives]= DrivePath[0];
                    AvlDrives++;
                    printf("\r\n%s",DrivePath);
                }
            }
         ++DrivePath[0];    //Scan to all scanable number of drives.
         uDriveMask >>= 1;
      }
   }
   return WorkState;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char DrivePath[]={"C:\\"};
    char CurrentDrive[]={"C:\\"};
DWORD Drives=-1;
int d=0;
for( d=0; d<26; d++)
    AllDrives[d]=' ';
Drives=GetAllDrives();
if(Drives >0)
{
    int Length= sizeof(AllDrives);
    for(int x=0; x<26; x++)
    {
        if(AllDrives[x]!=' ')
            {

                printf("\r\nFixed Drive : %c",AllDrives[x]);

            }
    }

}

   getch();
}
```

Comment: Side note - please don't apologize for your English. You're doing fine.

Comment: You know C++11 is a version of C++, and not C? So, shall that be C++ or C code? Or C#???

Comment: its does not matter either c or C++ (but not C#). but it should work for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use visual studio compiler to compile C and C++ in Windows, and it is available with its own IDE. When you install visual studio, it will install required libraries also to compile the C/C++ program. There are other IDEs and compilers available compatible with Windows like DevC++,CodeBlocks.